# Creating next and back button on tabs bootstrap 3 wizard?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to create a simple next and back button to show tabs in bootstrap 3 via data attr

Here is working fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/52VtD/9162/

Here is **HTML**

```
<div class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane active" id="1" data-step="1">1</div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="2" data-step="2">2</div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="3" data-step="3">3</div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="4" data-step="3">4</div>

</div>

<a href="#1" data-toggle="tab" class="step-back">back</a>
<a href="#2" data-toggle="tab" class="step-next">next </a>
```

But on last tab i have to show Finish istead of next, this is some kind of wizard, i have tried the bootstrap wizard but i does not work in 3.3 :(

Comment: Will the number of steps be the same, or will they be dynamic?

Comment: It would nice that if someone add new tab-pane that auto next and back work, and also in first step not to show back?

Comment: And just so you now, there's a Bootstrap wizard plugin available. http://www.panopta.com/2013/02/06/bootstrap-application-wizard-2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/52VtD/9197/

**HTML:**

```
<div class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane active" id="1" data-step="1">1</div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="2" data-step="2">2</div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="3" data-step="3">3</div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="4" data-step="4">4</div>

</div>

<a href="#1" data-toggle="tab" class="step-back">back</a>
<a href="#2" data-toggle="tab" class="step-next">next </a>
```

**JQ:**

```
$('.step-back, .step-next').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
  currentStep()
})


function currentStep() {    
  var currentVal = $('.tab-pane.active').attr("data-step");
  currentVal = parseInt(currentVal)    

  var prev = currentVal - 1;
  var next = currentVal + 1;

  $('.step-back').attr('href','#' + prev);
  $('.step-next').attr('href','#' + next);
}
```

1. event shown.bs.tab - This event fires on tab show after a tab has been shown [LINK](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs)
2. attr() is function to set new href value [LINK](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)