# Bootstrap 3 wizard?

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I already asked this question here
[Creating next and back button on tabs bootstrap 3 wizard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27067828/creating-next-and-back-button-on-tabs-bootstrap-3-wizard/27071692#27071692)

But I have exteded it now for adding finish at the last tab, but now i have problem to remove back button on first tab, here is my code

```
  $('.step-back, .step-next').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
            currentStep()
        })

        var previousButton = '<a href="#" data-toggle="tab" class="step-back">back</a>';
        var nextButton = '<a href="#" data-toggle="tab" class="step-next">next </a>';

        $(".wizard-navigation").html(previousButton + nextButton);

        function currentStep() {    
            var stepsLong = $('.tab-pane').length;
            var currentVal = $('.tab-pane.active').attr("data-step");
            currentVal = parseInt(currentVal);

            var prev = currentVal - 1;
            var next = currentVal + 1;

            if ( currentVal == stepsLong) {
                $(".step-next").html("finish").attr('href', '#step' + next);
            }
            else {
                $(".step-next").html("next").attr('href', '#step' + next);
            }

            if (currentVal == 0) {
                $('.step-back').addClass('hidden');
            }
            else {
                $(".step-next").removeClass('hidden');
            }


        }
```

Here is working fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/52VtD/9206/

What i need if user in on first tab to remove back button

Here is another working fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/52VtD/9207/

Comment: I can't see much in that fiddle - looks like you're missing a bunch of markup for the tabs. What about a data attribute to each tab, then on click check if $('.active').data('index') == 0 then $('.step-back').hide

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/52VtD/9207/

Comment: still no tabs - i'm expecting something like this for markup http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs

Comment: It is not styled like tabs, but it use boostrap data-toggle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/52VtD/9209/

I added this logic in your stepper:

```
 if(currentVal == 1) $('.step-back').hide()
            else $('.step-back').show()
```

this one fixes your clicking issue as well: http://jsfiddle.net/52VtD/9211/

your issue was that you were binding to .shown, but there was never a show event thrown, I added a tab("shown") to you init code.

Comment: Txanks, is ti problem with code that you must clikc twice

Comment: Txanks, this is great